# How to implement drag and drop between components

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, drag, angular-cdk

I want to implement drag feature for a div. The div lies in an overlay panel(like alert messages) and I need to drag those to the rest of the screen. (like, I need to drag an alert message div.)

Comment: [Use the CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview). Also, consider reading [ask] and providing a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways of doing it is using Angular Material `DragDropModule`.

Check out the official docs stackblitz example:
https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts